# Python complicated split function

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
_list = ['match','regex','find']
_str = 'find the match and then find the regex later on'
```

according to _list, able to split _str into: ?

```
['find',' the ','match',' and then ','find',' the ','regex',' later on']
```

**note that the split string maintain the *space* for the rest of the substr**

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to do? Be more specific.

Comment: given a string, find out all matched items in the list, and then split the string into a list but seperate out the matched items, while still keep the original sequence of the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Regex. `re.split`

**Ex:**

```
import re

l = ['match','regex','find']
_str = 'find the match and then find the regex later on'

print([i for i in re.split("("+"|".join(l)+ ")", _str) if i])
```

**Output:**

```
['find', ' the ', 'match', ' and then ', 'find', ' the ', 'regex', ' later on']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re.findall` with the following regex:

```
import re
print([s for m in re.findall(r'(^.*?|)({0})(.*?)(?={0}|$)'.format('|'.join(_list)), _str) for s in m if s])
```

This outputs:

```
['find', ' the ', 'match', ' and then ', 'find', ' the ', 'regex', ' later on']
```